# Maven 3.0 Plugin - how Do I set a goal that depends on another goal

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I'm working on a Maven plugin for building a custom package type.
I've got it packing and creating a fine. However, I have a previous goal that creates a library folder.

I want my build (package) goal to make sure the previous Lib goal was already run first.  How can I do that?

declaring the build class like so:

```
@Mojo(name = "build", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.PACKAGE,
      requiresProject = true)
@Execute(goal="lib", phase = LifecyclePhase.PREPARE_PACKAGE)
public class BuildComponent extends AbstractComponentMojo
```

and the lib class like so:

```
@Mojo(name = "lib", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.PREPARE_PACKAGE,
      requiresProject = true)
@Execute(goal="compile", phase = LifecyclePhase.COMPILE)
public class LibComponent extends AbstractLibMojo
```

That worked so both goals will run.  I'd like to just call 
`mvn groupId:build` instead of `mvn groupId:lib groupId:build` to have a successful build.

Am I missing some annotation processing at runtime? From what I've read I think I need a custom lifecycle to make this work. I've found the [Maven Lifecycle Extensions example](https://maven.apache.org/examples/maven-3-lifecycle-extensions.html) but I'm not sure how to use it to inject goals or phases into the lifecycle maven builds up and starts out with.

Comment: Why are you defining an `@Execute` ?

Comment: @khmarbaise, I thought it was a way to define a goal that would run first.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working. However I feel like I'm doing the [maven-2](/questions/tagged/maven-2) approach instead of the [maven-3](/questions/tagged/maven-3) one.  I'd love to see a **Maven 3.0** answer

Basically I removed the `@Execute` annotations since they weren't needed anyway.
Then I added the file `src/main/resources/META-INF/plexus/components.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<component-set>
  <components>
    <component>
      <role>org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.LifecycleMapping</role>
      <role-hint>wcc</role-hint>
      <implementation>
         org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.DefaultLifecycleMapping
      </implementation>
      <configuration>
            <phases>
              <process-resources>
                org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:resources
              </process-resources>
              <compile>
                org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:compile
              </compile>
              <process-classes>
                org.ucmtwine:ucm-maven-plugin:classpath
              </process-classes>
              <process-test-resources>
                org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:testResources
              </process-test-resources>
              <test-compile>
                org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:testCompile
              </test-compile>
              <test>
                org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:test
              </test>
              <prepare-package>
                org.ucmtwine:ucm-maven-plugin:lib
              </prepare-package>
              <package>
                org.ucmtwine:ucm-maven-plugin:build
              </package>
              <install>
                org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:install
              </install>
              <deploy>
                org.ucmtwine:ucm-maven-plugin:deploy
              </deploy>
            </phases>
      </configuration>
    </component>

    <component>
      <role>org.apache.maven.artifact.handler.ArtifactHandler</role>
      <role-hint>wcc</role-hint>
      <implementation>
        org.apache.maven.artifact.handler.DefaultArtifactHandler
      </implementation>
      <configuration>
        <!--the extension used by Maven in the repository-->
        <extension>zip</extension>
        <!--the type used when specifying dependencies etc.-->
        <type>wcc</type>
        <!--the packaging used when declaring an implementation of
          the packaging-->
        <packaging>wcc</packaging>
      </configuration>
    </component>
  </components>
</component-set>
```

And then in the application where I'm using the plugin
I set `<packaging>wcc</packaging>` and `<extensions>true</extensions>` where I declare my custom plugin.